# Spring-data-neo4j-4 Relationships common properties

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

i'm wondering if there is a way to specify a list of common properties for relationships withou defining new RelationshipEntity every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the common properties in an abstract class, making sure that the `@RelationshipEntity` annotation is defined on the subclasses.

However, that still doesn't take away the fact that you could potentially have many `@RelationshipEntity` subclasses. I'm assuming this is what you mean, but in case not, please edit your question to add more info/an example

Comment: Yes , the problem was defining many @RelationshipEntity , thank you for answer!